# in-tree include directory with bazel custom toolchain

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, bazel

Is it possible to configure a Bazel custom toolchain to include directories in the repository?

Assume that I have following in the root of my repository:

```
sysroots/armhf/include/myheader.h
sysroots/amd64/include/myheader.h

myproject1/component.cpp
myproject2/component.cpp
```

I'd like to configure toolchain such that when I run `bazel build --config armhf`, `component.cpp` files including `myheader.h` would get the header from `sysroot/armhf/include` directory, and when I run `bazel build --config amd64`, file from corresponding `sysroot/amd64` directory were used.

This needs to work without having to modify projects containing `component.cpp` files.

Essentially I would like to check in platform specific headers and binaries in the source repository along with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't found it yet, you need to write C++ toolchains. The [Configure C++ Toolchains Tutorial](https://bazel.build/tutorials/cc-toolchain-config) is a good place to start, if you have more specific questions they'll get better answers as separate questions. I'm going to answer specifically about the paths here.

Most of the paths are just normal paths relative to the [execution root](https://bazel.build/docs/output_directories). That typically means `external/<repo_name>/<package>/<name>` for paths in external repositories, or just `<package>/<name>` for paths in the main repository. [bazel-toolchain's pkg_path_from_label function](https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain/blob/9e71d562023dc7994e747110ee1ca345ad6b4413/toolchain/internal/common.bzl#L100) implements this logic, for example. In your case, that's `sysroots/armhf/include` for the first path.

cxx_builtin_include_directories is special. Paths there have unique syntaxes to generate absolute paths. The relevant one looks like `"%package(@your_toolchain//relative/clang/include)%"`, with `@your_toolchain` replaced with your repository's name. In your case that means something like `"%package(@//sysroots/armhf)%/include/myheader.h"`. Depending on where the package boundary is (deepest folder with a BUILD file) more or less of that might need to be in the `%package()` part.

Those directives get expanded when generating compiler command lines. I'm not aware of any documentation besides [the source](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/6d448136d13ddab92da8bb29ea6e8387821369d9:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcToolchainProviderHelper.java;l=309-329).

Comment: Brian, thank you! I have a custom toolchain definition but wasn't aware of the %package(@//...)% syntax. My problem is now solved for native bazel projects.

rules_foreign_cc still presents additional challenge since these projects are not built from execroot so relative include and library paths break. For the moment I'm working around by setting a CPATH env variable with correct path ($$EXT_BUILD_ROOT) with select statement. This clearly seems like rules_foreign_cc problem though so I'll follow up with them.